# How do I play multiple notes one after another in Tone.js

Tags: javascript, tone.js

I came up with this solution:

```
  for(var i=0; i < max; i++){
   
   var note=arrays[i].pitch;
   var time=arrays[i].timing;            
   if(i===0){synth.triggerAttackRelease(note,time,0)}
   if(i===1){synth.triggerAttackRelease(note,time,arrays[0].timing)}
   if(i===2){synth.triggerAttackRelease(note,time,arrays[1].timing+arrays[0].timing)}
   if(i===3){synth.triggerAttackRelease(note,time,arrays[2].timing+arrays[1].timing+arrays[0].timing)}
   if(i===4){synth.triggerAttackRelease(note,time,arrays[3].timing+arrays[2].timing+arrays[1].timing+arrays[0].timing)}
   if(i===5){synth.triggerAttackRelease(note,time,arrays[4].timing+arrays[3].timing+arrays[2].timing+arrays[1].timing+arrays[0].timing)}
   if(i===6){synth.triggerAttackRelease(note,time,arrays[5].timing+arrays[4].timing+arrays[3].timing+arrays[2].timing+arrays[1].timing+arrays[0].timing)}
   if(i===7){synth.triggerAttackRelease(note,time,arrays[6].timing+arrays[5].timing+arrays[4].timing+arrays[3].timing+arrays[2].timing+arrays[1].timing+arrays[0].timing)}
}
```

But it is too much code, and it can only play 7 notes or so;

Is there a simple shortcut for this in just a couple lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can declare the notes and their lengths in an array (you seem to be doing that). Then you can just loop over the notes and play them, accumulating the time delay to calculate the correct delay for each note from the start point.

e.g.

```
const synth = new Tone.Synth().toDestination();

const notes = [
    { pitch: "C4", timing: 0 },
    { pitch: "D4", timing: 1 },
    { pitch: "E4", timing: 1 },
    { pitch: "F4", timing: 1 },
    { pitch: "G4", timing: 1 }
];

function play() {
    let delay = Tone.now();
    for(let i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
        delay += notes[i].timing;
        synth.triggerAttackRelease(notes[i].pitch, '8n', delay);  
    }
}

play() // call this when someone interacts with your program.
```